# How to get the Request URLs for different links on a page in Java?

Tags: java, maven, web-scraping, css-selectors, jsoup

I am on this page: http://www.flashscore.com/nhl/. You see here the first table with 'Today's Matches'. If you click on a match, you get to the summary of the game.

There you can click on the 'H2H' tab and you get here: http://www.flashscore.com/match/Q1OevyV9/#h2h;overall. At this point if you open the developer tools, and you click on the network tab you can find out the Request URL.

I started to write a program in JAVA which gets all the Request URLs for all the H2Hs of those matches that are in the 'Today's Matchs' table.

```
  final Document page = Jsoup
        .connect("http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/tx_xlQp8HDC_pMu72He4")
        .cookie("_ga","GA1.2.47011772.1485726144")
        .referrer("http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/proxy-local")
        .userAgent(myUserAgent)
        .header("X-Fsign", "SW9D1eZo")
        .header("X-GeoIP", "1")
        .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
        .get();

}
```

So, with that code I got the page, but I have no idae how to proceed. Can somebody please help me, who has experience in WebScraping?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? What's the problem with your loop?

Comment: the problem is that I have no idea how to get the Request URL of the H2H tab of all the matches in the 'Today's Matches' table